# Exact representation of integers in floating points

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I am trying to understand the representation of integers in floating point format.

Since the IEEE floating point format have only 23 bits for mantissa, i expect any integer which is greater than 1<<22 to be only a approx representation. This is not what i am observing in g++

both of the cout below prints the same value 33554432.

Since the mantissa part is the one which is responsible for the precision how can we be able to represent (store) exact number which need more than 23 bits to be stored accurately.

```
void floating_point_precision(){
  cout<< setprecision(10);
  float fp = (1<<25);
  cout<< fp <<endl;
  cout<< (1<<25) <<endl;
}
```

As a followup based on the answer below why is the following code not executing "Not Equal" even though the print of both the fp,i are different.

```
void floating_point_precision(){
  cout<< setprecision(10);
  float fp = ((1<<25)+1);
  cout<< fp <<endl;
  int i = ((1<<25)+1)  ;
  cout<< i <<endl;
  if(i != fp)
    cout<< "Not equal" <<endl;
}
```

Comment: When I run your code, the first line prints `3.35544e+07`. Did you use an I/O manipulator to change the output format?

Comment: cout<< setprecision(10) maybe that caused it

Comment: Because the != operator converts the integer to a float before comparing. This loses enough precision for them to be equal.

Comment: sorry, silly mistake. Fixed :)

Comment: I've added `cout<< setprecision(10);` to the code in your question. See [mcve].

Comment: I've updated my answer with an illustrative example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's true that IEEE floating-point only has a limited number of mantissa bits. If there are 23 mantissa bits, then it can represent 2<sup>23</sup> distinct integer values exactly.

But since floating-point stores a power-of-two exponent separately, it can (subject to the limited exponent range) represent exactly any of those 2<sup>23</sup> values *times a power of two*.

`33554432` is exactly 2<sup>25</sup>, so it requires just one mantissa bit to represent it exactly (plus a binary exponent that denotes multiplication by a power of two). Its binary representation is `10000000000000000000000000`, which has 26 bits but only 1 *significant* bit. (Well, actually they're all significant, but you get the idea.)

You'll find that its neighboring integer values `33554431` and `33554433` *cannot* be represented exactly in 32-bit `float`. (But they can be represented in 64-bit `double`.)

More generally, the difference between consecutive representable values of type `float` varies with the magnitude of the value. On my system (most systems use IEEE format, but the standard doesn't require that), this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

void show(float f) {
    std::cout << std::nextafterf(f, 0.0) << "\n"
              << f << "\n"
              << std::nextafterf(f, f*2) << "\n";
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(24);

    show(1);
    show(1<<23);
    show(1<<24);
    show(1<<30);
}
```

produces this output:

```
0.999999940395355224609375
1
1.00000011920928955078125

8388607.5
8388608
8388609

16777215
16777216
16777218

1073741760
1073741824
1073741952
```

It shows the immediate predecessor and successor, in type `float`, of the numbers 1, 2<sup>23</sup>, 2<sup>24</sup>, and 2<sup>30</sup>. As you can see, the gaps get bigger for larger numbers, with the gap doubling in size at each power of 2.

You'd get similar results, but with smaller gaps, with type `double` or `long double`.

Comment: Based on your explanation , I have added another snippet which i don't understand

Comment: @David rather than moving the goalposts for a well-answered question, prefer asking another question. The more you pack into one question, the less general and less useful to future askers it typically becomes.

Comment: IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point has 24-bit significands. 23 are encoded in the significand field, and one is encoded via the exponent field. Mathematically, they have as 24-bit significands, which is why all integers from 0 to 2^24 can be represented exactly.